# Unable to see iPhone in MonoDevelop installed in Windows

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have installed Mono and MonoDevelop in Windows and trying to create an application for iPhone but I am not able to see iPhone while creating my solution. Can anyone guide me how to create an application for iPhone in MonoDevelop installed in Windows. 
Am I missing something or I need to install some more things to see the iPhone in Solution.

Thanks,
-Ankit

Comment: I am with you Ankit. I can't see it either. Isn't Dot NET development environment supposed to be platform free. Should be able to develop Iphone app on Windows? That's what Dot NET is all about.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it on Windows unfortunately. You need a Mac with XCode tools installed, and the iPhone SDK from Apple.

MonoDevelop with the iPhone development tools installed on a Mac will allow you to create MonoTouch apps.

Have a read over http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Installation for details on requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your input Michael. I have one more question in my mind is that "What is the difference between MonoDevelop and MonoTouch. Aren't both same? I thought MonoTouch is also and IDE to develop application.

Comment: MonoDevelop is the IDE, MonoTouch is a library that allows you to build applications to run on the iPhone under the Mono framework.